# cURL Post data from a file

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to send a POST request to a server and would like the post data to be in a file. The page is looking for the `number` parameter. Currently, I have this command:

```
curl -i -X POST 127.0.0.1:80/page.php -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary "@postdata.txt"
```

The problem with this is that it does not post the data. This is what's inside the postdata.txt:

```
number=100&other=data
```

Comment: I have no trouble running your exact command, posting to https://requestb.in/1b9c05k1?inspect . Perhaps there's something in page.php that's causing you to not see it coming through properly?

Edit: image of requestbin result in case the link expires: http://imgur.com/buB1kN0

Comment: Why don't you use `-d 'number=100&other=data'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do should work.  The issue is most likely that you are setting the `Content-Type` to `text/xml` and you're not sending xml, you're sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data.  Also, there's absolutely no need to use `-X` since you're trying to do a standard post.

Try removing the `Content-Type` and let curl set it automatically:

```
curl -i --data-binary @postdata.txt http://127.0.0.1/page.php
```

You can also use shell command substitution but it's not necessary:

```
curl --data-binary $(cat postdata.txt) http://127.0.0.1/page.php
```